# How to fix unknown command error in CMake, when I using Conan?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, conan

I've got CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(ip_filter LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(ip_filter ip_filter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ip_filter ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

At the same folder, I've got a conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
range-v3/0.9.1@ericniebler/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

When I tried to build it, using:

`$ cmake CMakeLists.txt`

I've got this output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/bogdasar/Documents/C++_Programming/ip_filter/conanbuildinfo.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (conan_basic_setup):
  Unknown CMake command "conan_basic_setup".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bogdasar/Documents/C++_Programming/ip_filter/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: The error message is `include could not find load file: /home/bogdasar/Documents/C++_Programming/ip_filter/conanbuildinfo.cmake`. Did you check if the file exists? Is the file correct?

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes, file don't exist. but in Conan documentation nothing is written about this file. What is he responsible for? What is inside it? Is it generated itself or should I write?

Comment: Did you run `conan install`? https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installing-dependencies

Comment: @ThomasSablik What should i install?

Comment: Please read the documentation I linked you. _It is very important to understand the installation process._ Stackoverflow is not a platform for conan/cmake tutorials.

Comment: Yes, please, do follow the Getting Started guide, make sure it works first: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html. Then, and only after succeeding, start doing modifications to those files trying to achieve your goal. Most likely you also want to start using the more modern packages in ConanCenter, those that don't have "user/channel", like that "ericniebler/stable". Check https://conan.io/center/range-v3/0.9.1/?user=_&channel=_

Comment: I did it, by using `conan install . --settings os="Linux" --settings compiler="gcc"`

Comment: The documentation link provided by Thomas Sablik for `conan install`. Here it is: https://docs.conan.io/1/getting_started.html#installing-dependencies This is for version 1 of conan. Version 2 of conan has some changes in invocations of `conan install --build` that lead to a missing  `conan_basic_setup` command when bumping a conan project from v1 to v2.

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck on the same issue for a while. After going through few threads I found the solution. Here I am summarizing the same.

Problem here is cmake is unable to find conanbuildinfo.cmake. This file should be generated when you call conan install.

If it is not getting generated then you should include cmake generator in conanfile.py. Like below:

```
generators = "virtualenv", "virtualrunenv", "cmake_find_package", "cmake"
```

or you can mention the same in your conan profile. Like below:

```
[generators]
cmake
```

Once this file is generated, cmake should be able to find it. And conan_basic_setup() step should pass.

Comment: I have that line, and still the same error